# Duplicate header with back page navigation

Tags: bug, new-nav

Okay, it's a bit hard to search for, so let me start with a screenshot so that it's directly clear if it's a duplicate (just to be clear, this has nothing to do with logging out):

[image]

So, reproducing it is a bit weird, but the minimal case I was able to find is as follows:

- Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-gcpm
- Go to another tab (my default is set to popular, so I went to the new tab)
- Open a question
- Go back, back

I was also able to once get a plain text result when going back instead of the double headers, but I wasn't able to reproduce that consistently. It happens with any tag and with other links as well.

---

Two more interesting observations:

1. It won't trigger if cache is disabled (which is often the case when you have devtools open)
2. It gives a Javascript error on `StackExchange.realtime.init(t)` saying that

   > Cannot read property '`init`' of `undefined`

   Or at least I think that's related.

Comment: Wow that was really weird.  I was able to reproduce this.  I can't reproduce it consistently, but I did stumble upon it once.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Consider how confused I was when I tried reproducing it with devtools open and it suddenly not triggering anymore... :P (Turns out having cache disabled prevents it from happening)

Comment: I have seen a bug report earlier, but I can't find it anymore...

Comment: @Andy At least that's another error of the same class yeah (messy ajax injections). Not sure though if solving one will solve the other, but might be.

Comment: That is the report @andy but I see that is related to login/logout. This one has a different root-cause by the looks of it