# Visual navigation bug on Microsoft Edge

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, new-nav, microsoft-edge

Sometimes (read: always) when switching tabs on the home page, and then pressing the browser's back button, the layout will mess up

[image]

Steps to reproduce

1. Navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&pageSize=30
2. Click any of the tabs 'new', 'popular' or 'need answers'
3. Click the browser's back button
4. Enjoy the view

This did not happen when I was trying to reproduce it on Chrome, so I assume its an Edge bug only, but I have no other browsers to test on so I'm not sure.

Microsoft Edge build 20.10240.16384.0

Comment: I saw this yesterday on Chrome for Mac, I thought my eyes were playing tricks on me so I honestly didn't think twice about it.

Comment: Repro'd, same build

Comment: I think this is just the new way to quickly double your rep

Comment: @CarrieKendall hmm.. maybe I should have kept it a secret then

Comment: This has actually popped up [multiple](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300164/weird-view-when-partially-logged-out) times on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300503/duplicate-header-with-back-page-navigation?lq=1) here [recently.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302804/what-happened-to-the-main-page?lq=1)

Comment: Sorry, I could not find those questions with queries I tried based on  my problem

Comment: I only found them because I remembered the first question had something to do with being logged out. They're not exactly titled the best for the most part.

Comment: @Kendra agreed but then again mine isn't perfect either

Comment: Edge, your father IE must be a proud man now.

Comment: The link in your question doesn't even work for me... 404.

Comment: @RobinKanters are you perhaps on your phone? Doesn't work for me either on my phone, but in the browser it's fine

Comment: @TimCastelijns I get a page not found on my phone, and on my desktop in Chrome and FF

Comment: @RobinKanters Are you using the new navigation? Because this issue, and the link in question, are on the new nav. (Hence the [new-nav] tag.) I'm pretty sure new nav isn't on mobile yet, which would also explain why it won't work on mobile for either of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the current release, but if you find new repro steps, please post them here.